# What is best practice for using and object over and over in runtime

Tags: c++, class, object, static, singleton

I have a class, named Contoller. I want to create one object from that class and change transactionValue and transactionId over and over in runtime. What is the best way for that. I think I can create one object from default constructer and use setControllerValues for new values. Is it best practice?

```
class Controller{
public:
    Controller();
    Controller(int,int);
    setControllerValues(int,int);
private:
    int transactionValue;
    int transactionId;
};


int main()
{
    Controller ct;
    ct.setControllerValues(3,4);
    ct.setControllerValues(6,7);
    ct.setControllerValues(34,45);
}
```

EDIT:I heard something about singleton. Should I use it for that?(I changed "skeleton")

Comment: Yes, this appears to be quite valid.

Comment: Aside from maybe using a better name for the method, or even individual methods for each value, I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a global! No, wait, globals are bad. Make it a singleton! No, wait, singletons are an anti-pattern. Pass it as an argument wherever it's needed! No, wait, tramp data is bad. Make it a global!

What's a person to do?

You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be considered good practice. There's nothing wrong there. Maybe you want to do some data validation before writing to your private members in `setControllerValues`. But a part from that that's pretty straight forward OOP you have there.

Comment: In fact it is a common pattern to avoid performance degration by object creation

Comment: @ckruse, there is a name for it: premature optimization, and is usually wrong thing to do.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I don't think that you really understood what the difference between „premature optimization” and „efficient coding” is.

Comment: ckruse, yes I did. saving a few instructions over the lifetime of the application while introducing much more possibility for bugs and making desing less flexible is not efficient coding. I have enumerated the drawbacks and there is only one advantage: a few cycles less. a poor tradeoff, as I said

Comment: @Jueecy, it was me. I explained the reasons in my answer and why I think it is not good practice in general. I wouldn't downvote if it said that sometimes it is good practice (which it can be). IMO, it is a poor choice for given example, which doesn't mean that it is always a bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

What you heard is probably [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), not skeleton.

For sure, you can use the approach you show, but let me ask you: why would you choose this instead of creating separate objects?

I don't like it for following reasons:

- if you really want to ensure a single instance over whole application, you need a proper singleton (not that I like it). Your current implementation doesn't stop anyone to create another controller
- it is much easier to handle multiple instances then shared access to single instance. What if you have to provide this object to other functions, or even worse, threads?
- it is easier to reason about immutable objects than mutable ones. Mutable state is the cause of good deal of bugs, as it gives more chance to invalidate the type invariants
- you actually gain nothing but the cost of calling a constructor which is cheap compared to other logic you need to execute

In short, I don't see any benefit in this approach, without knowing other requirements which might make it more justified. You have introduced a lot of added complexity to save a few instructions during object creation, which is optimized by the compiler anyway. It is a bad tradeoff, IMO.

With regard to singletons, in general I don't like them either :)
Here's why:

- I am very suspicious about the class itself knowing its lifecycle concerns (singleton, transient, per-thread, etc). This is something that clients usually know better
- It is much harder to test code relying on singletons
- shared state + multithreading = nights with debugger

That being said, sometimes they make perfect sense. However, you example doesn't seem to be such a case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Some programs are far easier to reason about if there is no mutable state (or very little); multi-threaded programs, for example.

Other object oriented approaches would say getters and setters are anathema.

In terms of performance and creating new objects on the stack, c++11 and the compiler are very good at working out the best way of creating efficient machine code, far better than you and me.

I would consider using the assignment operator. It allows you to use the values from one object to modify another:

```
class Controller {
public:
    Controller& operator=(const Controller& other) {
        transactionValue = other.transactionValue;
        transactionId = other.transactionId;
        return *this;
    }        
private:
    int transactionValue;
    int transactionId;
};
```

And use:

```
Controller permanent(12, 5678);
//...
permanent = Controller(23, 6789);
```